# Keyboard notifications cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I have an app that crashes when I try to handle **keyboard notifications**. I'm using xCode 6.0 and the project is in Swift.

Trying to isolate the problem I created a new app that contains only a `UITextView` with and 4 constraints that pin the view to top, left and right edges and set fixed height.

All that my `ViewController` has is the following:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.observeKeyboard()
  }
  override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter().removeObserver(self)
  }

  func observeKeyboard() {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:Selector(keyboardWillAppear()), name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object:nil)
  }

  func keyboardWillAppear() {
    println("keyboardWillAppear")
  }
}
```

When I launch the app in simulator,

> keyboardWillAppear

is printed to the console, and when I tap inside the text view, the app crashes with :

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1:
```

Error: `memory read failed for 0x0`

The keyboard is shown, but another `keyBoardWillAppear` is not printed to the console.

There is nothing else in this app, just the code above and 4 constraints. I have just opened brand new project trying to isolate the problem I have in my other app. I also tried to subscribe to notifications in `viewDidAppear`, and I also tried with another notification `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, but the result is always the same.

What am I missing? Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please share the sample project you have tried?

Comment: Your first problem is UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification should be UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.

Comment: Thank you Anil and @DBoyer. I tried with both notifications (and even some more keyboard related notifications). But my actual problem was the wrong usage of the selector in the 'addObserver'. It accepts a parameter so should be selector:"keyboardWillAppear:" and not what I've used in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making selector with return of function `keyboardWillAppear()`. Try making it using string: `Selector("keyboardWillAppear:")`.

Also a side note: You are registering keyboard notification in `viewDidLoad` which is usually called only once per view controller life cycle. It better to register for those notifications in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll move it there.

Comment: I found my own mistake. I should use: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillAppear:", name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil) - that is the keyboardWillAppear is a function that takes a parameter, that's why i think the error is: it try to access the arguments, but none passed.

Answer (score 1):

first solution is to sleep before hitting the head on the wall.

In the morning I figured out my problem. What I did wrong is the registration to the notification with wrong selector. There is a parameter passed to notification handler and so the selector should be: `selector:"keyboardWillAppear:"`, with a colon, specifying that this is a function that takes parameter.

So instead of:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:Selector(keyboardWillAppear()), name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object:nil)
```

I should be using:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillAppear:", name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

Thanks everybody who tried to help and I hope this will help other people new to Swift.